# How to show ascending and descending arrow image when click on each table head in Vue js?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have a listing page, data is fetching using laravel, When I click the table head `<th>` sorting in ascending and descending data will works. I need to show arrow marks downside and upside when sort works.

My Issue is:
At present when I click a table head `<th>` all table head arrow mark shows downwards. I mean when I click "Customer No", "First name" and "Last name" arrow marks showing downwards and upwards.

Actually I am expecting result is, when I click a table head, arrow mark reflects only one . Please check image and code given below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th v-for="key in columns" @click="sortBy(key)" :class="{active: sortKey == key}">@{{ colTitles[key] }} <span class="arrow" :class="order > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'"></span>
     </th>
 </tr>                   
 </thead>
 <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(index, item) in items | orderBy sortKey order">
            <td>@{{ item.erp_id }}</td>
            <td>@{{item.firstname}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/customer/details/') }}/@{{ item.id }}">@{{item.lastname}}</a></td>
            <td>@{{item.email}}</td>
            <td>@{{item.phone_1}}</td>
            <td>@{{item.status}}</td>
            <td>@{{item.created_on}}</td>
         </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**script.js**

```
new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            data: {
                sortKey: '',

                order: 1,

                columns: ['erp_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone_1', 'status', 'created_on'],

                colTitles: {'erp_id':'Customer No', 'firstname':'First name', 'lastname':'Last name'}
              },

 methods: {
                sortBy: function (key) {
                    this.sortKey = key;
                    this.order   = this.order * -1;
                    //alert(this.order = this.order * -1);
                    //alert(this.sortKey = key);
                    //this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
                    //order = order * -1
                }
            }
});
```

**style.css**

```
<style>
th.active .arrow {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        margin-left: 5px;
        opacity: 0.66;
    }

    .arrow.asc {
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #42b983;
    }

    .arrow.dsc {
        border-left: 4px solid transparent;
        border-right: 4px solid transparent;
        border-top: 4px solid #42b983;
    }

    #search {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

[image: Click Here]

Comment: Leave a comment if I've misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

## How to give each column its own order

If you want to give each column its own distinct sort order, then you will need to store a value for each order.

The following snippet is one way to achieve this. Each column is now associated with a `name` and an `order`. Sorting is done based on the values of the `activeColumn`, which is set when a table heading is clicked.

Additionally, I've made it so that the sort order only changes when the arrow is clicked. This way, the sort order doesn't always change when a new heading is selected.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    activeColumn: {},
    columns: [
      {name: 'firstname', order: 1}, 
      {name: 'lastname', order: 1},
      {name: 'email', order: 1},
    ],
    colTitles: {'firstname':'First name', 'lastname':'Last name', 'email':'Email'},    
    items: [
      { firstname: 'aaa', lastname: 'ccc', email: 'eee' },
      { firstname: 'bbb', lastname: 'ddd', email: 'ddd' },
      { firstname: 'ccc', lastname: 'eee', email: 'aaa' },
      { firstname: 'ddd', lastname: 'aaa', email: 'ccc' },
      { firstname: 'eee', lastname: 'bbb', email: 'bbb' },
    ]
  },
});
```

```css
th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #42b983;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #42b983;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns" 
            @click="activeColumn = column" 
            :class="{active: column == activeColumn}"
            >
          {{ colTitles[column.name] }} 
          <span 
                @click="column.order = column.order * (-1)"
                class="arrow {{ column.order > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc' }}" 
                >
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>                   
    </thead>

    <tr v-for="item in items | orderBy activeColumn.name activeColumn.order">
      <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td> 
      <td>{{ item.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

  <pre> Active Column: {{ activeColumn | json }}</pre>
</div>
```